# CSS Div % width issue

Tags: php, css, layout, width, percentage

I have the following code:

```
<div style='width:635px;height:20px;'>
<div style='float:left;margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:1px;width:".$neg."%;height:18px;background-color: #BF4F4C;'></div>
<div style='float:left;margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:1px;width:".$pass."%;height:18px;background-color: #E37A0D;'></div>
<div style='float:left;margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:1px;width:".$pos."%;height:18px;background-color: #9ABB59;'></div>
</div>
```

You can see that the '%' is a PHP variable - due to rounding, sometimes this equates to 101% and then the final bar is placed underneath the preceding two and not next to.  Anyway to stop this?

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/jVter/

**PHP**:

```
$pos = number_format(($row[1]/$row[0])*100,0);
$pass = number_format(($row[2]/$row[0])*100,0);
$neg = number_format(($row[3]/$row[0])*100,0);
```

**Further code** (this is a multi-query):

```
SELECT COUNT( ". $r ." ) AS Total, 
(SELECT COUNT( ". $r ." ) FROM  tresults    WHERE ". $r ." >=750) AS Engaged, 
(SELECT COUNT( ". $r ." ) FROM  `tresults` WHERE ". $r ." >=450 AND ". $r ." <=749) AS Passive, 
(SELECT COUNT( ". $r ." ) FROM  `tresults` WHERE ". $r ." <=449) AS Disengaged
FROM  `tresults`
```

Comment: You should probably post the PHP that's doing the miscalculation.

Comment: Can you show the PHP code that produces the variables? It's probably just a matter of needing to using `floor()` instead of `round()`.

Comment: Added the PHP code for you.

Comment: Not sure it is a miscalcultation but more a 'rounding' issue - just not sure how to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pos = number_format(($row[1]/$row[0])*100,0);
$pass = number_format(($row[2]/$row[0])*100,0);
$neg=100-$pos-$pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get the integer value, try using [floor()](http://php.net/floor) instead of [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format), which introduces rounding.

If you're trying to get a floating-point value instead, you will need to make sure your numbers add up to 100. You don't show the code that produces `$row` so it's hard to give you suggestions about that.

Comment: Is there any way via CSS to force the div to be in the same line?

Comment: Reason I ask is that floor will actually give incorrect figures (by the looks).

Comment: you could try setting `overflow:hidden` in the style of the outer container.